# Specify norestart on msi installation executed through visual c# app

Tags: c#, windows-installer

all!

I am using the COM object "Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library", in my C# project, to install a MSI package programatically:

```
using System;
using WindowsInstaller;

private static void InstallCOM(string msiPackage)
{
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
    Installer installer = (Installer) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    installer.UILevel = MsiUILevel.msiUILevelNone;

    installer.InstallProduct(msiPackage, "ACTION=ADMIN");
}
```

. But I don't know how to make this automatic, not restartable, installation. This `InstallCOM` method does an automatic, restartable, installation.

Thanks for some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of defects in the Windows Installer COM Automation Interfaces that cause problems when invoking it from Managed Code.  I suggest using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll (found in Windows Installer XML) instead.  This is a very well written interop library that wraps the Windows Installer Win32 API functions instead.

The client side code will pretty much be the same:

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
Installer.InstallProduct(msiPackage, "REBOOT=R");
```

Comment: I liked to see a more complete client side code for "Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" case, please.

Comment: That's all there is. The Installer class has a static method called InstallProduct.  There's no need to get a type, construct an object and cast it.

Comment: I am sorry! By the way, I asked a new question: [my new question link!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859081/specify-quiet-and-norestart-on-msi-installation-executed-through-visual-c-sharp). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using the ADMIN thing in the command line because it's nothing to do with no restarts.  I'm assuming you want an actual real install and not an admin install so just use the same as the msiexec command line option with REBOOT:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371101(v=vs.85).aspx

so you'd say REBOOT=ReallySuppress in the command line.

That will work only if it's Windows Installer that is deciding a reboot is needed. If there is code in the setup that explicitly does a reboot or overrides your reboot then there will still be a reboot.