# Specify quiet and norestart on msi installation executed, through visual c# app, by Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll (Windows Installer XML)

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

all!

I am using the dynamic library "Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" (from Windows Installer XML, that is, http://wixtoolset.org/), in my C# project, to install a MSI package programatically:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

private static void InstallWIXML(string msiPackage)
{
    Installer.InstallProduct(msiPackage, "REBOOT=R");
}
```

. But I don't know how to make this automatic, not restartable, quiet, installation. This `InstallWIXML` method does a manual (it is case dependent!), not restartable, not quiet (it is case dependent!), installation.

Thanks for some help!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code, like in my comment of the Christopher Painter's answer:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

private static void InstallWIXML(string msiPackage)
{
    Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);
    Installer.InstallProduct(msiPackage, "REBOOT=R");
}
```

.
It works for my question.

Thanks for the Christopher Painter's answer and comments, too!

Comment: How to check whether MSI installation is completed or not? Please guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Change REBOOT=R to REBOOT=R /QN.  Also realize that in a silent installation the installer can't ask for UAC elevation.  If the calling process isn't elevated and the MSI needs elevation it will fail.  This will likely be bubbled back up to the client as an exception.

Comment: Thanks! But, I checked again in internet, and found this link: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/577969/is-it-possible-to-disable-msiexec-help-gui). By the way, I used `Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);` with `Installer.InstallProduct(msiPackage, "REBOOT=R");`, and it worked to me, while you was answering this question. Then, I don't know if your answer is correct to this question. But, I am going to check it.

Comment: There are different ways to do it. You now have a good interop library to work with while your explore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, I found problems using `Installer.InstallProduct(msiPackage, "REBOOT=Q /QN");` in my testing application! I tested it with MS Windows XP OS!

Comment: Did I type REBOOT=Q?  Oops. REBOOT=R. Updated.

Comment: I am going to recheck it!

Comment: Thanks for your comments and your answer, Christopher Painter! But, I found problems using `Installer.InstallProduct(msiPackage, "REBOOT=R /QN");` in my testing application! I tested it with MS Windows XP OS!